# Storing days of month for one entity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-normalization

I have an `Event` table that contains the following columns:

```
ID
UserId
Title
StartDate
EndDate
Repeat (Check constraint (M,W,D)) -- Monthly, Weekly, Daily
Time
DaysId (FK)
```

**Question 1**

I want to add a column for storing many days of month like:

- Event 1 has to be repeated monthly in Month days (2, 4, 8, 23)
- is it a good idea to store them in one column separated by `(`, `|` or etc...)?
- is it a good idea to store them in another table as `MonthDays (ID, DayNumber)`?

Or is there any other way i can accomplish such thing for a fast and efficient way.

**Question 2**

`Events` table has a FK column days. which will be not null when the Repeat column value is `Weekly`. I'm storing days values in another table `Days` which has the following columns

```
ID
Mon (bit)
Tue (bit)
Wed (bit)
...
```

Is there a better way for storing the days?

Answer (score 0):

This will answer your question, but not quite as directly as you would like.

You seem to have an entity `eventScheduleRule` that defines one rule for an event.  This could be on the 3rd of every month.  Or the 4th Friday.  Or the Sunday after the first full moon of the vernal equinox.  Whatever rules you accept, you can have one rule that sets out one or more days for an event.

Then `event` would seem to contain one or more rules for scheduling the event.

I would suggest following a structure such as this for setting up the scheduling.